# Give an example of subsets $A$ and $B$ of $\mathbb{R}$ such that all three of the following conditions hold.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, connectedness

(a) Neither A nor B is open; 
(b) $A \cap B = \emptyset$;
(c) $A \cup B$ is open.

I've considered $A = (0,1] $ and $B=(1,2]$, and $A = (0,1] $ and $B=[1,2)$, but neither possible subset pairs satisfy all three conditions. Is this even possible?

Maybe it is possible if we consider infinite union subsets for $A$ and $B$. As in,

$A=\bigcup\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}(2n, 2n+1]$ and $B=\bigcup\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}(2n+1, 2n+2]$

so that $A \cup B = (0, \infty)$ which is open.

Comment: $A=\Bbb Q$ and $B=\Bbb R\setminus\Bbb Q$

Comment: @azif00, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BOEYSLlQy9s

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A very basic strategy could take two disjoint open intervals, and have them each "trade ownership" of a point from their interiors.

So, for example,

$$A = (0,1){\setminus}\{1/2\} \cup \{5/2\}$$

$$B = (2,3){\setminus}\{5/2\} \cup \{1/2\}$$

Comment: Wouldn't you want to include $\{1\}$ though? And is it necessary to swap two points? I think the following works: $$A = (0,1]\cup \{3/2\}$$

$$B = (1,2){\setminus}\{3/2\}$$.

Comment: Wait, nevermind, I see that B is now a union of two open sets and is thus open. You do need to swap two isolated points. And this also answers my concern about including $\{1\}$ because we have $A \cup B = (0,1) \cup (1,2)$ which is open.

Comment: I know you figured it out, but i thought it might be easier to see what's happening if the intervals don't abut each other, so I modified it.

Comment: In the version of your first comment you could also have left $\{1\}$ in $A$, but still swapped two points, and had a valid example that unioned up into a single interval, but I like the symmetric roles of $A$ and $B$ in my version.

Answer (score 0):

Take any $A \subset \mathbb R$ which is neither open nor closed and define $B = \mathbb R  \setminus A$.

Let us observe that we cannot find any two intervals $A, B$ with the desired properties.

Assume $A, B$ are intervals with these properties. Then each of  $A, B$ must be either a (bounded) closed interval or a half-open interval.

Let $A$ be an interval boundary point of $A$. W.l.o.g. we may assume that it is the right interval boundary point (the other case can be treated similarly). In order that $a$ becomes an interior point of $A \cup B$, we must have $B = (a,b]$ with $b > a$. Note that $B$ cannot contain $a$ and cannot be open. But then $b$ is the right boundary point of the interval $A \cup B$, thus $A \cup B$ is not open.